# Using the onload function in if/else statements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a page where depending on the time of day, the location of an image is different. So like a sun rising on the page depending on the hour--at 6am it's in the bottom left hand corner, at 7am it's a little higher, etc. I used an onload function for each of the sections, but the very last onload function seems to be overriding everything regardless of whether that section is the current time or not. Is there a way to cancel the onload function if it's not that hour of the day? Here's the gist of my script:

```
var today = new Date().getHours();
if (today >= 6 && today < 7) {
    document.body.style.background = "lightBlue";
    window.onload = generateSunball;
    function generateSunball() {
        var sunUp=document.getElementById("sunAppear");
        sunUp.style.display='';
        sunUp.style.position='absolute';
        sunUp.style.top='480px';
        sunUp.style.left='30px';
        sunUp.style.width='200px';
        sunUp.style.height='200px';
    }
} 
else if (today >=7 && today < 8) {
    document.body.style.background = "lightBlue";
    window.onload = generateSunball;
    function generateSunball() {
        var sunUp=document.getElementById("sunAppear");
        sunUp.style.display='';
        sunUp.style.position='absolute';
        sunUp.style.top='330px';
        sunUp.style.left='120px';
        sunUp.style.width='200px';
        sunUp.style.height='200px';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining `function generateSunball` multiple times, and these definitions are NOT scoped to the `if..else` block. The last one will be the only one left.

Consider trying:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // do stuff here
};
```

It's worth noting also that you could refactor your code fully. Something like...

```
switch(today) {
case 6:
    window.onload = ...;
    break;
case 7:
    ...
    break;
...
deafult:
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, define a single object with options:

```
var sunProperties = {
    "6":{
        "top": "480px",
        "left": "30px"
    },
    "7":{
        "top": "330px",
        "left": "120px"
    }
    ...
};
window.onload = function() {
    var sunUp = document.getElementById('sunAppear');
    sunUp.style.display = "";
    sunUp.style.position = "absolute";
    sunUp.style.width = sunUp.style.height = "200px";
    sunUp.style.top = sunProperties[today].top;
    sunUp.style.left = sunProperties[today].left;
};
```

There are many ways to solve the same problem. Pick one that suits you, but avoid copy-pasted code if you can ;)

Comment: Hahaha I'm still really new to this, but I'll definitely take your notes into consideration! Thanks :)